# makemigrations ModuleNotFoundError: No module named Insta

Tags: python, django

I had to re-do my project, and I copied the code from my files [names and directories are virtually the same]
When I try to make migrations, this error pops out.
I have insta in my `settings.py` at installed apps.

`File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'insta'`[I'm not sure if it will help, but here's my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruOXO.png)

I'm not really sure what to do, could someone help?

Comment: make sure you are in instaclone directory.

Comment: Your structure seems wrong. You have `instaclone/instaclone/*` which seems to be a project. Inside that project you have the root application `instaclone`.

 `insta` module is outside of that structure at `instaclone/insta/*` while it should be inside the project `instaclone/instaclone/insta/*` (in the same level as the root app).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Structure was the problem, it's fixed now. Thanks
after  moved `insta` into the folder `instaclone/instaclone` everything started working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).